# Prove that if $A$ is a square matrix, then $(A^{n})^{T}=(A^{T})^{n}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Exercise 1.3.40.a (*Fraleigh - Linear Algebra*):

Prove that , if $A$ is a square matrix, then $(A^{2})^{T}=(A^{T})^{2}$ and $(A^{3})^{T}=(A^{T})^{3}$.

Solution:

In general we have:

$(A^{n})^{T}=(A^{T})^{n}$

$\Big \langle Matrix\ definition \Big \rangle$

$((A_{ij})^{n})^{T}$

$\Big \langle Matrix\ power \Big \rangle$

$((A_{ij})_{1}\cdots (A_{ij})_{n})^{T}$

$\Big \langle Transpose\ of\ \ a\ product \Big \rangle$

$(A_{ij})_{1}^{T}\cdots (A_{ij})_{n}^{T}$

$\Big \langle \equiv \Big \rangle$

$(A_{ji})_{1}\cdots (A_{ji})_{n}$

$\Big \langle Tranpose\ matrix\ power\ simplification \Big \rangle$

$(A_{ji})^{n}$

$\Big \langle \equiv \Big \rangle$

$(A_{ij}^{T})^{n}$

$\Big \langle Matrix\ definition \Big \rangle$

$(A^{T})^{n}$

Is it correct?

Comment: Wow, sorry if I sound ignorant, but what kind of notation are you using? Are you listing properties? Are these equalities? Are you proving something? To me, it all looks very confusing...

Answer (score 6):

By induction: $\left(A^1\right)^T=A^T=\left(A^T\right)^1$, and if $\left(A^n\right)^T=\left(A^T\right)^n$ then
$$\left(A^{n+1}\right)^T=\left(AA^n\right)^T=\left(A^n\right)^TA^T=\left(A^T\right)^nA^T=\left(A^T\right)^{n+1}$$

Answer (score 4):

By a property of transpose product, $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$. Then $$(A^n)^T=(\underbrace{A\cdot ...\cdot A}_{n\ times})^T\underset{(*)}{=}\underbrace{A^T\cdot ...\cdot A^T}_{n\ times}=(A^T)^n.$$
To justify $(*)$ a simple induction can allowed you to conclude.

Comment: Property: Transpose of a product.